# Timer function reactJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, timer

this is my timer module. where it suppose to run code base on the timer code.

The problem i am facing now is that, The process flow works just fine but in the back end where the timer is set and suppose to send when a process is complete kinda did not work. This is because i set the timer with a value. But how do I set the timer to proceed to the next timer/step when the previous is complete?

If you can see in the output, The timer02 cant seem to find the file. But in the background the file is still generating. This is the timer problem rite? How do we set it to something like when you complete then it will proceed to the next task.

```
...
       app.post(('/timer02'),function(req,res)
         {
          res.send(serverdataTime02);
          console.log(`Timer Result Main (02) :`+ serverdataTime02);
         });
          console.log('1.3  The Retrieved File Is Extracted To JSON Format');
          console.log('...');
          console.log('1.4  Proceeding to List Any File That Is Uploaded To Google Cloud Bucket...');
          console.log('...');
          setTimeout(() => listFiles()
            .then(results =>
                {
                 app.post(('/timer03'),function(req,res)
                   {
                    res.send(serverdataTime03);
                    console.log(`Timer Result Main (03) :`+ serverdataTime03);
                   });
...
```

This is the output of the code.

[image]

Any ideas, solutions or links guys? really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to

app.post('/timer02',function(req,res) {

There should not be any parentheses around the path of the url.

Edit:

Make sure you add the next() function call to your previous route.
Something like this.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    next();
})

app.get('/timer02', function(req,res, next) {
    res.send(serverdataTime02);
    next();
});
```

Comment: It changes nothing dude.